# Javascript button switch between iframe sources

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to switch the source of an `iframe` when clicking on a button. What I've tried does not work.

```
<input type="image" id="pluto" src="pluto.jpg" alt="pluto" width="150px" height="150px" style="margin-left: 45%;" onclick="function()"/>

<script>
    document.getElementById('pluto').onclick = function() {
    {
        var property = document.getElementById(iframe);
        if (document.getElementById("something").src = "http://www.w3schools.com/";) {
            document.getElementById("something").src = "http://agar.io/";    
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("something").src = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
        }
    }
</script>
<iframe id='something' name="main" src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="border:none;width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:150px;"></iframe>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your DOM may probably be not ready at the moment of script execution.

Comment: Btw, what is `iframe`? Where do you declare it?

Comment: You compare it wrong - single `=` sign is an assignment operator. Moreover, you shouldn't have a semicolon in your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like, see the JavaScript [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

```
if (document.getElementById("something").src == "http://www.w3schools.com/") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntactical and semantical problems in here. First, you need to put all elements you're working with into DOM, so the script tag comes after. When selecting the iframe you want to use its ID, not the tag name. Also use the variable you defined instead of searching the element over and over. Then your comparison is an assignment - the single and double equation signs make a huge difference. As last, your condition should probably be more of

```
if A then B
else A
```

which means in text: if the URL is A, switch to B; otherwise (read url is B) switch to A.

This leaves us with code like this:

```
<input type="image" id="pluto" src="pluto.jpg" alt="pluto" width="150px" height="150px" style="margin-left: 45%;"/>

<iframe id='something' name="main" src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="border:none;width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:150px;"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('pluto').onclick = function() {
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("something");
    if (iframe.src == "http://www.w3schools.com/") {
        iframe.src = "http://agar.io/";    
    }
    else {
        iframe.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/"
    }
}
</script>
```

---

And here a shorter and smarter version using jQuery and the data attribute. It basically saves the alternative URL in an attribute and switches them on button press.

```
<input type="image" id="pluto" src="pluto.jpg" alt="pluto" width="150px" height="150px" style="margin-left: 45%;"/>

<iframe id='something' data-altsrc="http://agar.io/" name="main" src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="border:none;width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:150px;"></iframe>

<script>
$("#pluto").click(function() {
{
    var iframe = $("#something");
    var altsrc = iframe.data("altsrc");
    iframe.data("altsrc", iframe.attr("src"));
    iframe.attr("src", altsrc);
})
</script>
```